# Mostrar registros que se repiten cada mes

Tags: mysql, sql

He estando trabajando sobre una tabla de una base de datos, de la cual necesito mostrar los clientes que realizan por lo menos una compra todos los meses. Pero hasta ahora no he podido.

Les dejo la tabla y la consulta como debe aparecer, para que me puedan ayudar.

Tabla COMPRAS:

```
CLIENTES  MES_COMPRA
--------  ----------------
ANGEL     SEPTIEMBRE
BLANCA    SEPTIEMBRE
DIEGO     SEPTIEMBRE
FERNANDO  OCTUBRE
DIEGO     OCTUBRE
GABRIEL   OCTUBRE
BLANCA    OCTUBRE
```

Resultado esperado de la consulta:

```
CLIENTES
--------
DIEGO   
BLANCA
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nos cuentas que intentaste hasta ahora? esto lo resuelve un query de mysql o lo resolves en php? como sabes que meses buscar?

Comment: Tienes suerte de encontrarte con gente excesivamente amable pero este sitio no es un servicio de escritura de código. Acá resolvemos los problemas con nuestros códigos de forma colaborativa pero para ello hay que traer el código que no nos funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de esta manera con una subconsulta

**SUBCONSULTA**

```
SELECT cliente
    FROM compras
    WHERE cliente
    IN (
    SELECT cliente
    FROM compras
    GROUP BY cliente
    HAVING count( cliente ) >1
    )
    GROUP BY cliente
    ORDER BY cliente
```

**Lo que hice fue**

1. Selecciono la columna `cliente`
2. Pido que seleccione `cliente` donde `cliente` este dentro de una subconsulta
3. Dentro de la subconsulta, selecciono `cliente` y agrupo los resultados por esa misma columna
4. La indica con `having` que hago las anteriores acciones cuando tenga un conteo de  la columna `cliente` mayor a 1
5. Fuera de la subconsulta agrupo los resultados
6. Finlamente los resultados los ordeno

**CTE**

Si usas mysql desde la versión 8, puedes utilizar las `CTE` y tu consulta quedaría del modo siguiente

```
WITH consulta AS(
   SELECT cliente FROM compras
   GROUP BY cliente
   HAVING COUNT(cliente) > 1
)
 SELECT cliente FROM consulta WHERE cliente IN(SELECT * FROM consulta);
```

**Lo que hice fue**

> 1. Dentro de una consulta almacenada con un alias llamada `consulta` hice un `SELECT` donde agrupo los resultados siempre que el `conteo`
>      de cliente sea mayor a 1
> 2. Por fuera hago un `SELECT` pero no a la tabla si no a la `CTE` donde el `cliente` este en una consulta a la `CTE` **consulta**

Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=660f8a0f434f097744c105bd8dc18a3e) con ambos ejemplo para que los visualices y veas si te sirven

Comment: Gracias  shadow, pero creo que me explique mal, lo que en realidad necesito, son los clientes que al menos compran una vez en cada mes, es decir, “Angel” compro dos veces en septiembre, una en octubre y ninguna noviembre, pero “Diego” realizó una compra en septiembre, dos en octubre y una en noviembre, por lo que el resultado debe mostrarme solo al cliente Diego. Espero puedas ayudarme.

CLIENTES  MES_COMPRA
--------      ----------------
ANGEL     SEP
ANGEL     SEP
DIEGO      SEP
ANGEL     OCT
DIEGO      OCT
DIEGO      OCT
DIEGO      NOV

Resultado:
CLIENTES
--------
DIEGO

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas saber es los clientes que compran todos los meses podrías partir del siguiente análisis. Para que el cliente compre todos lo meses significa que debe tener al menos un registro por mes (debo agrupar por cliente y por mes) luego de ello saber cuantos meses tengo gestionados (supongamos que 12).

```
SELECT cliente, count(*) -- Agrupo a nivel de cliente
FROM (
    SELECT clientes, mes_compra, count(*) -- Agrupo a nivel de cliente y sus compras por mes
    FROM COMPRAS
) AS X
HAVING count(*) = 12 -- El comparativo de los 12 meses del año
```

**Nota:** Los 12 meses es número establecido por tí, dependiendo de los meses gestionados (en este caso 12), si este valor es distinto lo debes cambiar, de necesitar que sea dinámico deberías apoyarte en una subconsulta.

Answer (score 1):

todo depende... tal vez algo asi te sirva, debes tener en cuanta que la consulta arrojara los clientes que registren compras en los meses quemados en el where, asi que pon solo los que necesites

```
SELECT 
  CLIENTES 
FROM 
  COMPRAS 
WHERE 
  MES_COMPRA = 'ENERO' AND
  MES_COMPRA = 'FEBRERO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'MARZO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'ABRIL' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'MAYO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'JUNIO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'JULIO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'AGOSTO' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'SEPTIEMBRE' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'OCTUBRE' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'NOVIEMBRE' AND 
  MES_COMPRA = 'DICIEMBRE';
```

Comment: Por qué razón válida pasaste de usar OR Ahora a usar AND?

Comment: Por que con OR consultaba los clientes que registraran compras en al menos uno de esos meses, con el AND se consultan los clientes que tengan compras en todos los meses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   clientes
FROM
   compras
GROUP BY
   clientes
HAVING
   COUNT (mes_compra) =
      (SELECT COUNT(mes_compra) FROM compras)
ORDER BY
   clientes
```

No he comprobado esta respuesta, y puede tener errores.

El concepto es que la subconsulta calcula el número de meses distintos en la tabla entera.  Cada grupo tiene también un número de meses.  Cuando son iguales el grupo contiene todos los meses, y contribuye un valor de clientes.